# How to convert from xlsm to xlsx keeping the same name

Tags: vba, excel

how can I change the format from `xlsm` to `xlsx`. I need a script that will save a copy of the `xlsm` file with  `xlsx` extension,  but doesn't ask user to input file name, it needs to keep the original name, the only thing the user needs to do is select where to save the file.

```
Sub changeext()

Dim s_as As String

s_as = ThisWorkbook.FullName

s_as = Left(s_as, InStrRev(s_as, ".") - 1) & ".xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=s_as

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

End Sub
```

Comment: what are the exact issues you are having?

Comment: my code is prompting to enter the name of the new file, i need to make sure it automatically enters the name of the original xlsm file. user should not be able to rename the file.

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only want to add a .xlxs copy not write over your macro enabled workbook. Try the below line of code, it should work, put your workbook name in "put Workbook name here", the file left open will be the .xlsx file.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Put Workbook Name here" & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", _
ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: yeah this works great! it created the copy i needed, the only thing is that it automatically saves in the same folder as the original. how can i changed it so prompts me to select where do i want to save it? is that possible

Comment: Replace "Activeworkbook.Path" with "C:\Folder\SubFolder\" using the quotations. Replace the Drive letter, folder and subfolder names with where you want to save the file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create FolderPicker Function:

```
Sub changeext()
Dim objFolder As Object, objFSO As Object

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)

ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=objFolder & "\" & Left(ThisWorkbook.Name, Len(ThisWorkbook.Name) - 4) & "xlsx"

End Sub

Function ChooseFolder() As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder to save down the copy of this workbook"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, this code its great! it does exactly what i need but not sure why im getting an error message when I try to open the new file. it says "excel cannot open the file "filename.xlsx" because the file format or file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file." Not sure how solve this issue.

Comment: Because a . is needed before the "xlsx" change it to ".xlsx"